# Bulk insertion into neo4j with unique constraints

Tags: python, neo4j

I am trying to populate some data into a neo4j database. Due to the large amount of nodes and relationships, I am using bulk inserts as described in this guide:

[create-a-graph-database-in-neo4j-using-python](https://towardsdatascience.com/create-a-graph-database-in-neo4j-using-python-4172d40f89c4)

My Cypher statement looks like this:

```
UNWIND $rows AS row
MERGE (:Term {name: row.name, accession: row.accession, definition: row.definition})
RETURN count(*) as total
```

Because I'm using a unique constraint, if one node with the same accession already exists

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT accession on (n:Term) assert n.accession is unique
```

the merge fails with the following error:

```
{message: Node(2749) already exists with label `Term` and property `accession` = 'UO:0000000'}
```

Is there any way to do bulk creation of nodes unless the current node already exists, so I can only update some properties, in this case everything except the accession property.

thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think i solved this issue by setting the properties with simple SET clauses:

```
        UNWIND $rows AS row
        MERGE (t:Term {accession: row.accession})
        SET t.name = row.name
        SET t.definition = row.definition
        SET t.accession = row.accession
        RETURN count(*) as total
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).